# Storing Blobs in Seperate Tables with SQLite?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using this [SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) to benefit from 'unlimited' storage limits as a mobile application. Basically I have `base64 imagedata` and need to store this in a database.

In addition, I have some other tables and one Masterdata where the primary keys are stored along with some additional information, such as `albumName`.

**Relational setup with Foreign Keys**

To cope with the relational aspect of databases, I initially used Foreign Key declarations and created the tables as follows (for simplicity only two tables shown):

```
      // Master Data
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
        Masterdata(\
          id TEXT primary key, \
          albumName TEXT, \
          favorite INTEGER\
        )"
      )

      // Images
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
        ImagesData(\
          id TEXT, \
          data BLOB, \
          FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Masterdata(id)\
        )"
      )
```

Then, when I wanted to load only the images of a specific album, I run the query:

```
SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data FROM ImagesData, Masterdata WHERE Masterdata.album = (?) ["Some album name"]
```

This worked fine (everything loads as it should), however I noticed immediately that it gets Slow when dealing with a large dataset. This makes sense as base64 strings are quite storage extensive.

**Store Blobs in Separate Tables**

So I read this [post](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/BP_Optimizing_SQLite_database_performance_1219781_11.jsp), *which recommends to consider storing each BLOB in a separate table*, if your data includes BLOBs.

I coded this as follows:

```
// tableName in the form of 'id'_imagesData
// 'id' is stored also in Masterdata

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + tableName + "(id integer, data BLOB)"
);
```

and then I insert the data in this table with the query:

```
"INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (id, data) VALUES (?,?)", parameters
// parameters = [0, base64_imageData_Str]
```

**Outcome**

The outcome is that I noticed a significant increase in the loading time, even when having stored multiple images (thus having multiple tables). It looks to me that it makes sense as we can use the Masterdata to filter out the selected album `id`'s and then only load the images from one table.

**My questions are:**

- Is this a bad, oke, or good practice?
- Are there disadvantages of having a large number of tables (for example, if I have 1000 images, I will have 1000 tables with this setup)
- If it is bad practice, what is the better recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing each blob in its own table is definitely **not** the way to go. I think the article is recommending your first approach, which should be fine, except that your query is wrong.

```
SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data
FROM ImagesData, Masterdata
WHERE Masterdata.album = 'some name'
```

This joins one row in `Masterdata` with *every row* in `ImagesData`, even if the `ImageData` doesn't belong to the `Masterdata`. You need to add a join condition:

```
...
WHERE Masterdata.album = 'some name' AND ImageData.id = Masterdata.id
```

Or better yet, use the explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data
FROM Masterdata
INNER JOIN ImagesData ON ImagesData.id = Masterdata.id
WHERE Masterdata.album = 'some name'
```

Also make sure that `Masterdata.id` and `ImagesData.id` have indexes.

Comment: Thanks for that. So If I understand well, you recommend to execute one single query on a table with big size, instead of muliple smaller queries. Is there any evidence you know about?

Comment: @JohnAndrews Both your and my queries are just one query each; yours however returns every image in `ImagesData`, which of course takes a long time to read if it's big. My query only returns the `ImageData` associated with the `Masterdata` object.

Comment: Ah yes I see. I was more thinking of how storing an image in seperate Tables differd from your query?

Comment: Could you also explain your words what "having an index" means? Does it mean that you define the id as primary key in both tables - I didnt get that concept. Thanks!

Comment: [Indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) make retrievals faster when filtering on a column in exchange for a bit of insert performance. Making a column a primary key implicitly creates an index on it, but also makes the column unique, which may not be what you want.

Comment: The explicit statement is not working for me, resulting in error ambiguous column name ImagesData.data....

Comment: Basically tried: SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data FROM Masterdata, ImagesData INNER JOIN ImagesData ON ImagesData.id = Masterdata.id WHERE Masterdata.album = (?) ["default"]
---> gives the above mentioned error. When executing the following then it works:: 
SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data FROM Masterdata, ImagesData. Removing INNER JOIN also works...

Comment: When using "AND ImageData.id = Masterdata.id" it works fine. My question then becomes, will this have performance issues as opposed to the Explicit Statement?

Comment: Remove the `ImagesData` table from the `FROM` clause; it's already provided via the `JOIN`. Not sure what you mean by the "explicit statement".

Comment: Thanks for the help Colonel. I have started digging into the Indexes, and opened a new thread with some questions I have. If you feel like answering, you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604545/how-to-use-sqlite-create-index

Answer (score 0):

Well if its image only why not store directly in directory as an image and have the name and hash of that image in database. This will allow u to reduce your load time further.
Hash will let you check in future for if an update has happened on server. Watsapp and other messengers do that.

Keeping it in apps protected directories will ensure no one has access.

If too many files then consider breaking into folders->sub folder->file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with ngCordova file but I kept getting encoding error5; so far nobody has provided a solution to it (seems to be quit often an issue)

Comment: i am asking out of curiosity. if image is saved in directory of your phone. giving a path only in image attribute of html (without using ngcordova file extension) e.g. "file://img/image_id.jpg". doesnt this acheive what you are currently trying?

Comment: I think it could indeed affect it. I tried it with and without the prefix but kept getting the error, it seems to be quite common: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006469/how-to-save-canvas-to-phone-using-ngcordova