# How to use SQLite Create Index?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I am using the [SQLite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) for my data needs. In my database, I stored tables containing base64 imagedata and other characteristics (such as album name etc.).

Now I want to optimize my data retrieval using SQLite Indexes, as I noticed that retrieving large amounts of imagedata can take some time.

I am however unsure on which columns to use the Indexes, which type (e.g. do I need Unique Indexes or Composite Indexes) and how the queries are processed? See also [description](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm).

**My setup is as follows:**

Table (Columns)

```
Masterdata: (id, albumName, favoriteBoolean, dateCreated)
ImagesData: (id, data)
ThumbnailsData: (id, data)
```

**My questions:**

- Which type of Index do I have to create to optimize the performance in this example?
- Do I have to create the index only once (when table is created)?
- On which Columns and Tables do I need to apply the `CREATE INDEX` command?
- Perhaps an explanation of how it works

**Anex: Data retrieval**

When I for instance want to retrieve all the ImagesData with `albumName = "foo"`, I use the following syntax:

```
SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data FROM Masterdata, ImagesData WHERE Masterdata.id = (?) AND ImagesData.id = Masterdata.id
```

An alternative would be `INNER JOIN`, but I think that the above does the same (true or not?).

Comment: For an explanation, see the documentation: [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html); [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Comment: Thanks for that. Quick question: is it sufficient just to create the index on the ID? No need to include an additional syntax in the query? Like  SELECT Masterdata.id, ImagesData.data FROM Masterdata, ImagesData WHERE Masterdata.id = (?) AND ImagesData.INDEXCOLUMN = Masterdata.INDEXCOLUMN